# How to make complex thead sticky to top of window

Tags: html, css, html-table, sticky

I have a table with pretty complex structure `thead`. So I can't know scales of rows and cells of `thead` before table's body will be filled (it contains hundreds of rows information). How should I make `thead` sticky to the top of window, when I scroll down?

`thead`'s  structure looks like this:

[image]

I can't divide `thead` and `tbody` by `div` or wrap `thead` by `div` because `thead`'s structure depends on `tbody` content. I can't change the CSS `display` property of 'thead'  because it kills all structure.

I tried to copy `thead` + `tbody`'s first row to other table and toggle `display:none` by scroll but original `thead` different from copied because original's `tbody` have other content.

thead structure: http://jsfiddle.net/ba14fyex/

Comment: Can you give a jsfiddle with youre code? So we can look at it. You should probally work with position: fixed top: 0 right: 0

Comment: I added jsfiddle with thead and first row

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it by copying table without body to `div` so i've got:

```
<div id='wrapper'>
   <table id='copy'>...</table>
</div>
<table id='origin>...</table>
```

And using jQuery I copy all width and height properties from origin to copy:

```
$(function(){
    var origin = $("#origin"),
        curTablePos = origin.position().top;

    $("#origin thead th").each(function(i){
        var replic = $($("#copy thead th")[i]),
            $this = $(this);

        replic.width($this.width());
        replic.height($this.height());
    });

    $("#copy").width(origin.width()); //setting up width

    $(window).scroll(function(e){
        var wrapper = $("#wrapper");
        if(window.scrollY >= curTablePos){
            wrapper.show();
        }else{
            wrapper.hide();
        }
    })
});
```

Please comment if you can do it better, because I find this solution pretty hardcore html-porn.

Answer (score 0):

I had a website with same problem and solve it this way. It clones the header when scrolling. I'll be glad if it helps.

https://codepen.io/DannaB67/pen/ayvXWe

**CSS**

```
body {
  background: #fefefe;
}
table {
  width: 720px;
  border: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 0 0;
}
thead {width:720px;}
table th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: LightCyan;
  padding: 0 10px 0;
  height: 40px;
  width: 710px;
  text-align: left;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
table td {
  padding: 10px;
  border-color: #9fdaed;
  border-right: none;
  border-left: none;
}

$nav-height: 120px;

.navbar-fixed {
  position: fixed;
  width:720px;
  top: -($nav-height); left:0px;
}
```

**JS**

```
(function($) {
"use strict";

var $navbar = $("#navbar"),
    y_pos = $navbar.offset().top,
    height = $navbar.height();

$(document).scroll(function() {
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (scrollTop > y_pos + height) {
        $navbar.addClass("navbar-fixed").animate({
            top: 0
        });
    } else if (scrollTop <= y_pos) {
        $navbar.removeClass("navbar-fixed").clearQueue().animate({
            top: "-20px"
        }, 0);
    }
});
```

});

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <thead id="navbar">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="5">1</th>
      <th colspan="9">2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="3">3</th>
      <th rowspan="3">4</th>
      <th rowspan="3">5</th>
      <th rowspan="3">6</th>
      <th></th>
      <th colspan="3">7</th>
      <th colspan="3">8</th>
      <th colspan="3">9</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>10</th>
      <th>11</th>
      <th colspan="2">12</th>
      <th>13</th>
      <th colspan="2">14</th>
      <th>16</th>
      <th colspan="2">17</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>18</th>
      <th>19</th>
      <th>20</th>
      <th>21</th>
      <th>22</th>
      <th>23</th>
      <th>24</th>
      <th>25</th>
      <th>26</th>
      <th>27</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="table-row">
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>1881</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td style="color:green;">2270</td>
      <td style="color:green;">1318</td>
      <td style="color:green;">138</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```